# emberjs select from predefined range of options

Tags: ember.js

I have a controller called kitsController and a kit object that has a property called nodes. Nodes is a number between 1 and 5. But those numbers arent related to any other controller, would i still use the ember.select ? a view? other? eg:

```
{{#view 
contentBinding="App.kitsController"
valueBinding="nodes" 
tagName="select"}}

what goes here to:
a) iterate the options 1 - 5 ?
b) show the selected value ?
c) update the value of the property on change ?

{{/view}}
```

and additionally, what if the property was country and i had a huge list?

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in Ember.Select view.  I'm not sure if it can work with just numbers - all the examples I've seen involve an array of Model objects - overkill for your (and my) case.

Comment: Yeah it seems overkill, unless it can be extended somehow but I can't work that out.. I was hoping for something like knockout's data-bind="options: someSimpleArray

Comment: Someone else helped me with pretty much this same problem: http://jsfiddle.net/maml/WFbQP/4/.  Still having problems with b) & c) though